# how to install officegen module in node webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Well, I am new to node webkit can any one help me out for the below issue?

I want to use 'officegen' plugin into node webkit executable package but not working for me. See the below code.

I have the officegen folder in same place where this JS is placed.

```
var officegen = require('officegen/lib/index.js');
```

Error message : Error: Cannot find module 'officegen/lib/index.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to the same path, prepend `./`, otherwise it will resolve to `node_modules` in the current or a parent directory.

```
var officegen = require('./officegen/lib/index.js');
```

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Comment: I tried but still getting the same error.Error: Cannot find module './officegen/lib/index.js'

Comment: @pratiknagariya Are you sure the path to officegen is relative from the file you call `require` in? Not your application root?

Comment: Yes file path is relative from the file where the 'require' is written.

Comment: Hmm, it should work, but maybe this is related to node-webkit, see https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Using-Node-modules#3rd-party-javascript-modules

Comment: The easiest solution should be to do `npm install officegen` and `require('officegen')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I had given incorrect path.